# client browser is getting redirected back to the ADFS service after successful authentication

Tags: c#, .net-core, adfs

I am trying to integrate ADFS with my .net core 3.1 web application. I am able to reach our ADFS page but It appears that after successful login the client browser is getting redirected back to the ADFS service.

startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddWsFederation(options =>
        {

            // MetadataAddress represents the Active Directory instance used to authenticate users.
            options.MetadataAddress = "MetadataAddress";

            // Wtrealm is the app's identifier in the Active Directory instance.
            // For ADFS, use the relying party's identifier, its WS-Federation Passive protocol URL:
            options.Wtrealm = "Wtrealm ";

            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;


        })
         .AddCookie();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var user = context.User;
            if (user == null || !user.Identities.Any(identity => identity.IsAuthenticated))
            {
                await context.ChallengeAsync(WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                        await next();
            }
        });
}
```

Error message: Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidRequestException: MSIS7042

Comment: I dont have an answer for you - i am a bit of a newbie myself. but if you are setting up an auth server, take a look at an api server I configured. the startup file is here - https://github.com/Jay-study-nildana/ProjectWTPublicRepos/blob/master/apiservers/dotnetcoreapiserverwithauth0/dotnetcoreapiserverwithauth0/Startup.cs . this is not an answer but a full file for you to refer, if it helps at all.

Comment: Isn't that a configuration setting in the application in the ADFS server?

Comment: @Duston what do you mean?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app scroll down to the "Redirect URI" section.  That's what I had in mind.

Comment: Thanks @Duston. My .net Framwork application is working fine. This fact is confusing me

Comment: @Duston, just to clarify things, it  is authenticating me with ADFS but the problem that it s going in a loop instead of taking me to my controller